# Multiple where conditions with related data

Tags: entity-framework

I have a situation where I need to apply some filters to the query, so I have a class representing the filters:

```
public class ReportNoteFilterDto
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
}
```

and I need to select data according this filters.

```
var query = _db.User;

if (filter.Month > 0 && filter.Month <= 12)
    query.Select(u => new {
        User = u,
        Notes = u.Notes.Where(n => n.Begin.Month == filter.Month)
    });

if (filter.Year > 2011)
    query.Select(u => new
    {
        User = u,
        Notes = u.Notes.Where(n => n.Begin.Year == filter.Year)
    });

var results = query.Include("Notes.Foo.Bar").ToList(); //doesn't work
```

I need to select Notes.Foo.Bar too.

How can I do this multiple filters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You did not assign the result of first query to *`query`* variable</strike>

You can see here how a similar problem has been solved:

```
class Program
{
    //A simple class to hold the results
    public class Result
    {
        public string Item { get; set; }

        public IQueryable<string> Collection { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list1 = new List<Result>();
        var objects = list1.Select(o => new Result { Item = o.Item, Collection = o.Collection.Where(a=> a.Length == 10) });
        if(true)
           objects = objects.Select(o => new Result { Item = o.Item, Collection = o.Collection.Where(a=> a.Length > 15) });
    }
}
```

Comment: But .Select returns an IQueryable but query is DbSet. I cann't implicit convert it and .AsQueryAble() doesn't works too :(

Comment: Doesn't work too.Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Database.Domain.User>'.

Comment: Yes, Now I found out that you create another anonymous object. let me correct it

Comment: Unfortunately the same error :( - Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#2>'

Comment: It keeps skipping the first query :(

Comment: I think I can't use two selects because one stops the other, only .Where can be used like this. Just a guess.

Comment: Not necessarily, but chaining multiple where clauses feels more natural than chaining select clauses. think of joins also that might be the key to your problem.

Comment: I'll try it again later and mark as answer if works. Thank for you help.